# Need row as column

Tags: sql, format, row

Hi I am working with SQL and I need some help with the following table:

```
      ID_enterprise | ID_workplace | Service | Address | N_Workers |
           1              1            X         A1         50       
           1              1            Y         A2         50
           2              2            Z         A3         10
           2              3            X         A4         5
           3              4            Z         A5         5
```

And I need  this format:

```
      ID_enterprise | X | Y | Z | Address1 | Address 2 | Address 3 | Address 4 | AddressN | N_Workers1 | N_Workers2 | N_Workers3 | N_WorkersN | T_Workers
           1          1   1   0      A1        A2          NULL        NULL        NULL        50           50          NULL           NULL        100
           2          1   0   1      A3        A4          NULL        NULL        NULL        10           5           NULL           NULL        15
           3          0   0   1      A5        NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL        5            0           NULL           NULL        5
```

The AddressN and N_WorkersN are for enterprises wich have more than 3 workcenters (The biggest has 9). So I think that I need something dinamic...

Sorry about my english and my poor explanation!
Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a dynamic pivot query.  Try Googling for this, and if you get stuck then come back here.  Also, which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Thx for the help. I will google for Dynamic Pivot Query!

Answer (score 1):

You can use PIVOT, here's an example query using a subset of the data you provided.

```
WITH input_data AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'X' AS service FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'Y' AS service FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'Z' AS service FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'X' AS service FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS id, 'Z' AS service FROM DUAL
)
SELECT * FROM input_data
PIVOT (
  MAX(service) FOR service IN ('X' AS x, 'Y' AS y, 'Z' AS z)
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try! If I have success I will tell you!